# flutter web firebase auth

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

**Hear is my Code**

```
void verifyPhoneNumber() async {
 await auth.signInWithPhoneNumber("+91$phoneNumber").then((confirmationResult) {
         var verificationId = confirmationResult.verificationId;
      }).catchError((error) {
        print(error);
      });
}
```

But it is not working. when I run it the Web app show this type error.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'settings')